# PHP structure in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code and works fine:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true);
```

I want delete characters `,` and insert `<br />` with code like this:

```
echo str_replace(",", "<br />", get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true));
```

But, how can I put both of codes correctly in PHP?

If I put this, it won't work:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true);
echo str_replace(",", "<br />", get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true));
```

Comment: The codes looks fine. What's the problem?

Comment: i don't know how mixing both codes in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID; 
echo str_replace(',', '<br />', get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true));
?>
```